# check if radio button is checked using shared preferences

Tags: android

i am able to save the checked radio button using shared preference and load preferences every time app starts but i want to add some code to the radio buttons i.e check if a radio button is checked and perform an action such as showing a toast for each radio button individually .the action should not fire every time the activity starts because im trying to set notification after a specific period using AlarmManager, so calling the method again would reset it

```
package com.example.radiogroup;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 RadioGroup radioGroup;
 TextView textCheckedID, textCheckedIndex;

 final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener);

        textCheckedID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkedid);
        textCheckedIndex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkedindex);

        LoadPreferences();
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener radioGroupOnCheckedChangeListener =
      new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

     RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
     int checkedIndex = radioGroup.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);

     textCheckedID.setText("checkedID = " + checkedId);
     textCheckedIndex.setText("checkedIndex = " + checkedIndex);
     SavePreferences(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, checkedIndex);
    }};

 private void SavePreferences(String key, int value){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putInt(key, value);
  editor.commit(); 
 }

 private void LoadPreferences(){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
  int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
  RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
  savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
 }
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 1" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 2" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Option 3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedindex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i have tried

```
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
        jTextField1.setText("Welcome");
    }
    else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
        jTextField1.setText("Hello");
    }
```

but it doesnt perform any action

Answer (score 0):

[**`RadioButton.isChecked();`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29) is what you need to use. if checked return `true`

```
private void LoadPreferences(){
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
  int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
  RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
  if(!savedCheckedRadioButton.isChecked())
          savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

}